# Why jQuery more/less toggle script won't work in WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, function

I am trying to add more/less toggle script on my text, and it won't work.
It should show at start of page loading height of 25px of the text, and full height, or auto heihght after button for height, button of jquery script is pressed.
I can't get it working on wordpress.

Works on fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Wut5E/

And i tried on two different ways.
With shortcodes, of course.

```
function piki( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $url = '/?s=';
    $str = '';

    $output = array();
    $count = 0;

    foreach (explode(", ",$content) as $content) {
        $count++;
        $output[] = "<a href='" . $url . $content . "'>" . $content . "</a>";
        if ($count == 50) {
            break;
        }
    }
{ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.more').click(function() {
    if(jQuery('.piki').css('height') != '25px'){
        jQuery('.piki').stop().animate({height: '25px'}, 200);
        jQuery(this).text('More...');
    }else{
        jQuery('.piki').css({height:'100%'});
        var xx = jQuery('.piki').height();
        jQuery('.piki').css({height:'28px'});
        jQuery('.piki').stop().animate({height: xx}, 400);
        // ^^ The above is beacuse you can't animate css to 100% (or any percentage).  So I change it to 100%, get the value, change it back, then animate it to the value. If you don't want animation, you can ditch all of it and just leave: jQuery('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'100%'});^^ //
        jQuery(this).text('Less...');
    }
});
</script>
<div id="piki" class="piki" style="height: 25px; overflow: hidden;"><?php echo implode(", ", $output); ?></div><a class="more" style="float: left;" href="#stay_here">Read more <br><br></a>
<?php }
}
add_shortcode( 'piki', 'piki' );
```

or this way

```
function piki( $atts, $content = null ) {
    $url = '/?s=';
    $str = '';

    $output = array();
    $count = 0;

    foreach (explode(", ",$content) as $content) {
        $count++;
        $output[] = "<a href='" . $url . $content . "'>" . $content . "</a>";
        if ($count == 50) {
            break;
        }
    }
{ ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.more').click(function() {
    if(jQuery('.piki').css('height') != '25px'){
        jQuery('.piki').stop().animate({height: '25px'}, 200);
        jQuery(this).text('More...');
    }else{
        jQuery('.piki').css({height:'100%'});
        var xx = jQuery('.piki').height();
        jQuery('.piki').css({height:'28px'});
        jQuery('.piki').stop().animate({height: xx}, 400);
        // ^^ The above is beacuse you can't animate css to 100% (or any percentage).  So I change it to 100%, get the value, change it back, then animate it to the value. If you don't want animation, you can ditch all of it and just leave: jQuery('.show-more-snippet').css({height:'100%'});^^ //
        jQuery(this).text('Less...');
    }
});
</script>
<?php }

    return '<div id="piki" class="piki" style="height: 25px; overflow: hidden;">'.implode(", ", $output).'</div><a class="more" style="float: left;" href="#stay_here">Read more <br><br></a>';
}
add_shortcode( 'piki', 'piki' );
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: your fiddle works fine, then what is the error on your WP site?

Comment: I think I solved it, javascript should be loaded after div.

Comment: You could solve that by wrapping the contents of your <script> tag in a jQuery(document).ready(function() { … }) block. Then it'll run after the whole page has loaded & been parsed. http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/